# Combining variable with $_GET in php?

Tags: php, variables

I need to pass a filename to this script

https://github.com/ThomasDepole/Easy-PHP-Tail-/blob/master/tail.php

so i can create a link like

```
http://somedomain/monitor/index.php?log=1574930149
```

The script comes with a variable defined like this

```
$logFile = "/path/to/file";
```

I've tried changing it to

```
$logPath = "/path/to/";
$logName = $_GET[log];
$logFile = $logPath.$logName;
```

It looks correct if I

```
<?php echo $logFile; ?>
```

but the script is unable to print the file as it is supposed to.

What am i doing wrong?

Also, what should I do to prevent

```
http://somedomain/monitor/index.php?../../path/to/a/different/file
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that. You're allowing users to spit out the contents of **ANY** file on your server. consider `index.php?log=../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: try `$_GET['log']` instead of `$_GET[log]`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I can answer the first part, but for sanitizing the log file path, please reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911382/sanitize-file-path-in-php)